# Exporting a Processing Application to Web Processing IDE

Tags: javascript, java, processing, processing.js, processing-ide

I am working with `Processing` trying to develop a simple data visualization application for the number of people with Health Insurance in the US.

I have the sketch working locally on my machine but I have tried to export it for the web using the Javascript mode available from within the Processing IDE.

A folder is generated with a number of files including a HTML page and the JS file for the sketch. However I am getting this error when I try to load the page from my `LocalHost`

```
Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to execute pjs sketch: ReferenceError: ListstateMarkers is not defined
```

My entire code for my Sketch (in Java) is here:

```
UnfoldingMap map;

List<Marker>stateMarkers;
List<Feature>states;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  smooth();
  map = new UnfoldingMap(this);
  MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);
  states = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "ushealthinsurance2005.json");
  stateMarkers = MapUtils.createSimpleMarkers(states);
  stateMarkers = MapUtils.createSimpleMarkers(states);
  map.addMarkers(stateMarkers);
}

void draw() {
  map.draw();
  for (int i = 0; i < stateMarkers.size(); i++) {
    Marker state = stateMarkers.get(i);
    //Get information when mouse over a county.
    if (state.isInside(map, mouseX, mouseY)) {
      state.setColor(color(255, 0, 0));
    }
    else {
      state.setColor(color(0, 0, 255));
    }
  }
}
```

I should point out I am also using a Maps Library `Unfolding` to generate the Map tiles and add interactivity to the application.

Has anyone any Idea what might be going on here? Is this a glitch with the IDE itself? Has anyone ran into a similar problem?

The line throwing the error from within the JS file is this one:

```
   throw "Processing.js: Unable to execute pjs sketch: " + e;
```

There are over 10,000 lines of generated code making it very difficult to actually debug the problem.

Appreciate any advice or help on the issue.

Comment: I am not aware of the Unfolding library but if you're using any libraries that have Java dependencies then they're not going to run on Javascript giving you a `Reference not defined...` error. You will have to find Javascript alternatives for these libraries. Seeing that you have some 10,000 lines of code and if you made your program with Java libraries, you may have a lot to do to revise everything. So before you make any changes, I'd look around the internet. You may find related posts on Processing forum.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo is right Unfolding is a java library, won't work on js mode. Besides his suggestion you might consider exporting an applet. Would work in browser, but with a lot of scaring warnings...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Java libraries in JavaScript, so you can't use them in Processing.js.

You have three options:

**Option 1:** Find a JavaScript library that does the same thing. Unfortunately, [Unfolding Maps does not support JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586554/unfolding-for-processing-2-1-fails-in-javascript-mode), so you'll have to use something else. The GoogleMaps API might be worth checking out. **If you want to embed your application in a website, this is the only real option.**

**Option 2:** Deploy as a runnable jar. You can use something like [JarMatey](http://staticvoidgames.com/JarMatey/) (note: I wrote JarMatey) to package your Processing sketch as a self-extracting runnable jar. You won't be able to embed this in a webpage, but you might use [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javawebstart/index.html) to make deploying over the web easier.

**Option 3:** Deploy as a packaged executable. Processing can export applications, but they require library directories instead of coming as a single file. Instead, you can create a runnable jar and then use something like [JWrapper](http://www.jwrapper.com/) to create a single-file executable.

**Note:** Deploying as an applet isn't really an option. Applets are pretty much dead, and they'll be a huge pain for both you and your users. Applets will be deprecated in Java 9.